# Swapping mips value of array without temporary register

Tags: mips

So I am trying to convert this to mips.

```
void swap (int *px, int *py) {
int temp;
temp = *px;
*px = *py;
*py = temp;
}
```

I thought it might be something like

```
sll $t1, $a1, 2
add $t1, $a0, $t1
lw $t0, 0($t1)
lw $t2, 4($t1)
sw $t2, 0($t1)
sw $t0, 4($t1)
jr $ra
```

but I am not allowed to use a temporary register.

I think I have to use a few lw/sw commands but I don't see how you can do it.

Comment: Technically you're already using 3 temporary registers ($t0, $t1, $t2). You need to be more specific about what exactly you can and can't use.

Answer (score 2):

There're two solutions to this:

1) **Math**

```
void swap(int &x, int &y)
{
     if(*x != *y)
     {
         x = x - y;
         y = y + x;
         x = y - x;
     }
}
```

**NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS METHOD. It can cause overflow in some cases.**

2) **XOR** (use this)

```
void xorSwap (int *x, int *y) 
{
     if (x != y) 
     {
         *x ^= *y;
         *y ^= *x;
         *x ^= *y;
     }
 }
```

[Wikipedia about XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

I left the MIPS code part for you to implement one by yourself ;)